# Why is my JUnit Plugin tests failing with unresolved bundles errors?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to get my JUnit Plugin-Test launcher to run for my PDE projects. It was working before, but I changed some of the names of my OSGi bundles and now it's failing with the following:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.904
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.904
!MESSAGE Bundle me.gladwell.android.tools_0.1.1.qualifier [76] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 me.gladwell.android.tools 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.904
!MESSAGE Package uses conflict: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy; bundle-version="2.1.0"
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.904
!MESSAGE Bundle me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android_0.3.1.qualifier [77] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.905
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle me.gladwell.android.tools_0.1.1.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.905
!MESSAGE Bundle me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.test_0.3.1.qualifier [78] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.test 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.905
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.test 2 0 2011-08-09 15:43:59.905
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle me.gladwell.android.tools_0.0.0.
```

Please see [full error log](https://gist.github.com/1134495)

I'm unsure how to diagnose these messages and where/what problems they might refer to. These tests run successfully in my command line, Tycho-Maven build and the project compiles without errors in Eclipse. I've selected "all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" option in [my launcher](https://raw.github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/master/me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.test/%5Bme.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.test%5D%20test.launch)'s "Launch with" select box.

Any ideas why I'm getting these error messages?

Comment: In the launch-configuration in the plug-ins tab, which type of "Launch with" do you have selected? Can you share the `.launch` with us?

Answer (score 0):

If you're reusing the launch configuration and you've changed anything with the plug-in metadata (like their names), you need to be sure it's "clearing the configuration space".  You'll find this option on the Configuration tab of the launcher.

Comment: Thanks, but this is definitely checked and the tests still fail. I've also deleted the temporary workspace created by the unit tests and I still get the same error message.